# Is it possible to sync Netezza User Groups with Active Directory Groups?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, netezza, active-directory-group

Does anyone know if it's possible to synchronize Netezza User Groups with Microsoft Active Directory (AD) groups?

My client's Netezza appliances already require a user to connect using their network uid and pw via a connection to the LDAP server. But they would like to use AD Groups across various data platforms. Right now, they have to maintain an AD Group for a particular data set and a corresponding Netezza User Group for the same on the Netezza platform. Is there a way to synchronize the two so two separate groups don't need to be maintained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is certainly possible
We have developed a script that export two CSV files from active directory
1) The first file contains a list of all the groups that corresponds to a specific naming  convention (begins with G_NZ)
2) The second file contains a list of every user in each of these groups with the group name next to the user name
3) Based on other portions of the naming conventions of these groups the script grant them specific rights in specific data bases and schema corresponding to a similar naming convention 
4) The last step is to create all the users from the file and delete those no longer in the file and add those  users to the right groups

An example:
A database called PROD_EDW has a schema named DBO and the group G_NZ_PROD_DBO_R gives read access to all Objects and that schema

I hope you can follow

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think I follow you. You export one CSV file of AD Groups; and then you export another CSV of all users assigned to these groups. Do you then use scripting on the Netezza host server to update the corresponding Netezza User Groups? Or can you modify the NZ User Groups via the NZ admin user interface? I'm also wondering if there's a way to automate this process so that the AD and NZ Groups stay closely in sync...?

Comment: We load the two files into tables on Netezza and basically ‘full outer’ join to the catalog tables (_v_user, _v_group and _v_usergroups) .. after the AS-IS and TO-BE images has been compared we loop over the resulting (few) rows and do most if the rest in python generating SQL. All is scheduled to run daily (22:00 as I recall it)

Comment: Python is really not a prerequisite, but Perl, bash, even awk will do it, but make so pure to do all of it in Linus’s on the host - even the extraction from AD. That is possible if your Linux version is new enough and you install the right packages

Comment: Very helpful, Lars. Thanks for the additional detail re. your implementation. I definitely appreciate that you're advising that this be scripted entirely on the Netezza host server. I believe we are running Red Hat Enterprise 6... which is 2010 vintage, if I'm not mistaken. I'm going to run this solution past my team and see what our Netezza experts say. I'll be back to let you know the result!

Comment: Do you remember offhand why the Linux version needs to be current for this to work? Is it the connecting to Microsoft Active Directory part?

Comment: Yes, a package for LDAP querying is necessary. Of course you CAN do that elsewhere and transfer the two files to the nz host afterwards, but it’s extra complexity...

Comment: Thanks Lars. Looks like we're going to give this a try. I really appreciate your help in outlining a solution!